# Find the path of an image file in a text file and hand over the file path to poshgram

Tags: powershell, telegram

Background: I am using the file and folder watcher "DiskPulse" (Win 10) to identify a new image files (.png) in several folders. DiskPulse saves a new text file (`C:\diskpulse.txt)` containing an image file path, and calls a powershell (ps) script that sends the new file to telegram. I am using the poshgram module to send the new file to telgram.

**Problem 1:**
To send the new file, its file path and name needs to be identified first from a text file deposited by the file and folder wather DiskPulse (`C:\diskpulse.txt)`. I only know the file extension (`*.png`) and the beginning of the file path (`C:\*`) of the new image file beforehand. Also, I am not sure if I should use -SimpleMatch or -Pattern for the search. The content of diskpulse.txt looks like this:

> "03-Oct-2020 11:38:04 Modified    29.54 KB    administrator C:\local\files\snapshots\nameofimagefile.png"

**Problem 2**:
The identified file path needs to be handed over to poshgram (the $photo variable specifies the file path for poshgram).

This is the code for the ps-file I came up with so far:

```
Select-String -Path C:\diskpulse.txt -SimpleMatch "*.png"|select FileName

$token = 
$chat_id = 
$photo = here, the file path from the search should be inserted
Send-TelegramLocalPhoto -BotToken $token -ChatID $chat_id -PhotoPath $photo
```

Any pointers are highly appreciated, I am on a steep learning path here.

---

The solution Doug has posted works well. In addition, this is the complete solution I found myself after the comments put me on the right path (the substring after the text "administrator " is selected from the text file):

```
$token = " "
$chat_id = " "

$photo = (Select-String -Path C:\diskpulse.txt -Pattern "administrator (.*)").Matches.Groups[1].Value

#in case a substring should be extracted according to the character position ("61" in this particular case), use this instead:
#$photo = (Get-content -Path C:\diskpulse.txt).Substring(61)

Send-TelegramLocalPhoto -BotToken $token -ChatID $chat_id -PhotoPath $photo
```

Comment: the output of `Select-String` will be a match object ... and there will NOT be a  `.Filename` property on that object. [*grin*] save the result of the  `S-S` call to a $Var and then use `$Var | Get-Member` to look at what you have in that $Var.

Comment: I receive en error message that I need to specify the object when using this code. How can I specify the object properly?: ***$Var = Select-String -Path C:\diskpulse.txt -SimpleMatch "*.png"***
$Var | Get-Member

Comment: so the file is just ONE LINE that starts with the timestamp and ends with the full file name? is there ever a space in the file or path? you can use `$InString.Split(' ', 7)` to get the string split into 7 parts ... and then take the last part for your file name.

Comment: I did not get `$InString.split` working, however this code accomplishes what I needed to do: `$token = " "
$chat_id = " "

$photo = (Select-String -Path C:\diskpulse.txt -Pattern "administrator (.*)").Matches.Groups[1].Value

#in case a substring should be extracted according to the character position ("61"), use this instead:
#$photo = (Get-content -Path C:\diskpulse.txt).Substring(61)

Send-TelegramLocalPhoto -BotToken $token -ChatID $chat_id -PhotoPath $photo` Thank you for setting me on the right path!

Comment: kool! glad to know that you got it working as needed ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use select string with an appropriate regex pattern to extract the file names.

```
$photo = (Select-String -path 'c:\diskpulse.txt' -Pattern 'c:.+\.png' -AllMatches).matches.value
```

Since you know it will always be `C:\` we can match the start with `c:` and the end of course with `.png`. `.` in regex will match any character so we have to escape it with `\` to say "literally a period"